# Getting elements from a list that contain any string from two other lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, wildcard

Basically searching items from a list that contains combined elements from two other lists. Also, all the items in the three lists are individual strings.

Example:

```
Paths = ['ab01', 'bc02', 'cd03', 'de04', 'ef05']
str1 = ['b','e']
str2 = ['3', '4']

# desired output
out = ['de04']       # only item in Paths that contains both elements from str1 and str2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use list-comprehension with `any()`:

```py
out = [
    p for p in Paths if any(s in p for s in str1) and any(s in p for s in str2)
]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['de04']
```

Answer (score 1):

this solution could help you achieve your goal, it will work with any number of paths and strings, Best of luck !

```py
Paths = ['ab01', 'bc02', 'cd03', 'de04', 'ef05']
str1 = ['b','e']
str2 = ['3', '4']

out = ['de04']

def program(paths, *lists):
    out = []
    for path in paths:
        bools = [any([x in path for x in l]) for l in lists]
        if all(bools):
            out.append(path)
    return out


if __name__ == "__main__":
    out = program(Paths, str1, str2)
    print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension for this, but it's a bit complicated.

First you can iterate through each value in `Paths`, as `i`:

```
[i for i in Paths...]
```

But then you need to check if a value from str1 or str2 exists in i, these can be done with more list comprehension as below (not these lines will not work on their own unless you define `i` to test:

```
[j for j in str1 if j in i]
[k for k in str2 if k in i]
```

The above will return a list of the characters from each str that exist in `i`.  A useful thing in python is that an empty list will automatically evaluate to `False`, and a populated one will evaluate to `True`, so you just need to put these comprehensions into the first one, after an `if` statement:

```
out =  [i for i in Paths if [j for j in str1 if j in i] and [k for k in str2 if k in i]]
print(out)

['de04']
```

Although the below replaces i,j and k to be a bit more readable:

```
[path for path in Paths if [elem1 for elem1 in str1 if elem1 in path] and [elem2 for elem2 in str2 if elem2 in path]]
```

This code basically does the same as below, but in a single line. I have included the below to help with understanding:

```
out = []
for i in Paths:
    list1 = []
    for j in str1:
        if j in i:
            list1.append(j)

    list2 = []
    for k in str2:
        if k in i:
            list2.append(k)

    if list1 and list2:
        out.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic solution:

```py
>>> Paths = ['ab01', 'bc02', 'cd03', 'de04', 'ef05']
>>> str1 = ['b','e']
>>> str2 = ['3', '4']
>>> out = []
>>> for i in range(len(Paths)):
...     for j in range(len(str1)):
...         if str1[j] in Paths[i]:
...              for k in range(len(str2)):
...                  if str2[k] in Paths[i]:
...                      out.append(Paths[i])
...
>>> out
['de04']
```